# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{n \sin{\frac{x}{n}} }dx$

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }  \int_0 ^{\pi/2} \sqrt{n \sin{\frac{x}{n}}} dx$ .

I already have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n \sin{\frac{x}{n}}}= \sqrt{x}$.

So I'm trying to use DCT so that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n = \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$.

But I'm having a hard timer finding a bound.

Also, I'm a little concerned about the range of $x$, can we still use the DCT with the range?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $0\le\sin\tfrac{x}{n}\le\tfrac{x}{n}$ for $x\in[0,\,\pi/2]$, so you can use $\sqrt{x}$ as your upper bound on the integrand in the DCT.

Answer (score 1):

You can have much more that the limit since, without any restriction (except $n>0$), $$I_n=\int\sqrt{n \sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}\,dx=-2 n^{3/2} E\left(\left.\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi -\frac{2 x}{n}\right)\right|2\right)$$ So
$$J_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{n \sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}\,dx=n^{3/2} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2-2
   E\left(\left.\frac{(n-1) \pi }{4 n}\right|2\right)\right)$$ Expanding as series
$$J_n=\frac{\pi ^{3/2}}{3 \sqrt{2}}\Bigg[1-\frac{\pi ^2}{112 n^2}+\frac{\pi ^4}{84480 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right) \Bigg]$$